# Firebase auth() and other function is not

Tags: reactjs, firebase

did i set the code correctly.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
  import "firebase/auth";
  import "firebase/firestore";

  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "AUTH",
    projectId: "projectId",
    storageBucket: "storageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
    appId: "appId",
    measurementId: "measurementId"
  };
  
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  export default firebase;
```

I am install npm install firebase
and npm install firebase --save
firebase.auth() function no.
function auth() no.

Comment: npm --version
8.15.0

Comment: Make sure you are following the instructions for the version of the Firebase SDK that you've chosen.  v8 and v9 are entirely different.

Comment: npm firebase --version
8.15.0

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link right under it for that purpose) to include that version number, where you got that information from, and the exact error message and stack trace you get.